# Decision tree: Perfect classification with (a dicotomic) class noise at 100%, but almost null prediction with noise at 99%. (Tried 2 alg in R). Why?

Tags: r, machine-learning, cart, weka

I am using a dataset with a dicotomic class and testing how noise affects the decision tree j48 - from Rweka, using R - performance. I´m adding noise, and using confindence factors from 0.01 to 0.5 along the experiment.

As the class is dicotomic, it makes perfect sense that the worst performance of the training set is at 50%, being the class dicotomic.

Now... as the validation goes down, I´ve some points where the accuracy is almost perfect when the noise is total. How can I explain that?

[image]

Red is for the training set; Blue for the validation (80/20)

accuracy = (correctly predicted class / total testing class) × 100% OR, The percentage of correctly classified instances (TP + TN)/(TP + TN + FP + FN). where TP, FN, FP and TN represent the number of true positives, false negatives, false positives and true negatives, respectively.

The dataset I´m using is a random sample (10%) of this one https://www.kaggle.com/ludobenistant/hr-analytics

Here´s my code:

```
library(arules)
library(RWeka)
library(readr)
library(caret)
library(caTools)


setwd("C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Desktop\\AA")
inputFileName = "hr.csv"

ruido = function( datasetName, percentage ) {
  hr = read_csv(datasetName)

  sample = sample.split(hr$left, SplitRatio = percentage / 100)
  toModify = subset(hr, sample == TRUE)
  NotModify = subset(hr, sample == FALSE)

  toModify$left = sapply(toModify$left, function(x) !x )

  new_hr = rbind(toModify, toNotModify)

  output = strsplit(datasetName, "[.]")
  outputFileName = paste0(output[[1]][1], '_ruido_', percentage, '.', output[[1]][2])

  write.csv(new_hr, file = outputFileName, row.names=FALSE)
  outputFileName
}

set.seed(101) 
percentages = seq(0, 100 )
confidenceFactors = seq(0.05, 0.5, 0.05)

dataset = read.csv( inputFileName, sep = "," )

sample = sample.split(dataset$left, SplitRatio = .8)
train = subset(dataset, sample == TRUE)
test  = subset(dataset, sample == FALSE)

dir.create(file.path("C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Desktop\\AA", "datasets\\5"))
write.csv(train, file = "datasets\\5\\HR_train.csv", row.names=FALSE)
write.csv(test, file = "datasets\\5\\HR_test.csv", row.names=FALSE)

sizeResults = data.frame( "CF" = double(), "Percentage" = double(), "Value" = integer(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
accuracyResults = data.frame( "CF" = double(), "Method" = character(), "Percentage" = double(), "Value" = integer(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for( percentage in percentages ){

    percentage = percentage / 100

    # load training dataset
    outputFile = ruido( "datasets\\5\\HR_train.csv", percentage * 100 )
    training = read.csv( outputFile )
    training$number_project = as.factor( training$number_project )
    training$time_spend_company = as.factor( training$time_spend_company )


    for( c in confidenceFactors ){
      # create tree
      print( paste0("Decision tree for: ", "percentage=", percentage, ", CF=", c) )
      tree = J48( as.factor(left) ~ ., training, control = Weka_control(M=2, C=c) )
      treeSize = tree$classifier$numElements()
      sizeResults = rbind(sizeResults, data.frame(CF=c, Percentage=percentage, Value=treeSize))

      # test tree
      pred <- predict(tree, test, type='class')
      trainingAccuracy = summary(tree)$details[[1]]
      testAccuracy = confusionMatrix(table(test$left, pred))
      accuracyResults = rbind(accuracyResults, data.frame(CF=c, Percentage=percentage, Method="Entrenamiento", Value=trainingAccuracy))
      accuracyResults = rbind(accuracyResults, data.frame(CF=c, Percentage=percentage, Method="Validaci�n", Value=testAccuracy$overall[[1]] * 100))
    }
}


ggplot(data=sizeResults, aes(x=Percentage, y=Value)) +
  geom_point() +
  ylab("Nodes") + # Set axis labels
  scale_colour_hue(name="")       # Set legend title  

ggplot(data=accuracyResults, aes(x=Percentage, y=Value, group=Method, color=Method)) +
  geom_point() +
  ylab("Accuracy") + # Set axis labels
  scale_colour_hue(name="")
```

Comment: So what is the bottom axis? The percentage of the dataset that is represented by random noise??

Comment: @Josh it´s the noise % in the class. 
The class is dicotomic, so a 100% noise means all the class labels got inverted.

Comment: I see... And now I see you're referring to that single blue dot with the arrow. Wow!

Comment: Yes. Do you know what that may be?

Comment: no clue! This feels like more of a coding question and might do better in stack overflow

Comment: I tried. They sent me here. Lol.

Comment: How big is the data? Could you do an example of the problem without this file writing stuff that makes it difficult to follow. As I understand it you put the variable train in a file and then use that file to make another file to get the variable training from this file, a scrambled version, in which you're not just flipping but also reorder by sampling into two sets and binding these again. So much happening. What happens if you just do the 100% flipping without all the other stuff. I can only imagine that the prediction would be complete opposite. Do you flip the 'test' somewhere as well?

Comment: Martijn, The "ruido" (noise in spanish) function receives the 80% of the dataset (the training set) , then divide that in 2 (based on the noise %. If we want noise at the 10%,we divide the training in 90/10. The first part is not modified. To the 2nd we add noise. We rejoin that, fix the confidente factor and build the tree. Then we validate the results with the 20% that we left intact at the beginning. The ds has 1500 rows, 10 cols. Does this help?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings would you please check my follow up question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285449/weird-decision-tree-results-when-adding-noise-to-the-class

Comment: @Josh would you also please check it? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285449/weird-decision-tree-results-when-adding-noise-to-the-class